# MYSQL UPDATE rows matching on condition based of variables

Tags: mysql, sql

In a phone system scenario i have 2 tables.

- table1 is composed by: `customer_id`, `call_duration`, `calldate`, `skip_billing` .
- table2 is composed by: `customer_id`, `bonus_seconds`.

table1 stores all the calls for all customers and table2 stores the bonus_seconds which represents free conversation time allowed for a defined customer(ie: for customer 1 the FIRST 40 cumulative seconds are free).

I have to write a query to update table1 according to the condition explained below:
set skip_billing within calls which are defined free in table2.

So I first need to group by customer_id and then iterate over the calls, incrementing a cumulative variable(cumsec) over call_duration and set skip_billing accordingly.

table1 example is:

```
|customer_id |billsec | skipbill|
|1           |12      | 0       |
|1           |10      | 0       |
|1           |15      | 0       |
|1           |8       | 0       |   <--need to set 1 due to cumsec=45 for customer_id=1
|2           |12      | 0       |   <--nop
|3           |12      | 0       |   <--nop
|2           |12      | 0       |   <--need to set 1 due to cumsec=24 for customer_id=2
|1           |12      | 0       |   <--need to set 1 .... 
|3           |15      | 0       |   <--need to set 1 due to cumsec=27 for customer_id=3

|customer_id |bonus_seconds|
|1           |40           |
|2           |20           |
|3           |15           |
```

How I can write a query or procedure in SQL to achieve this behaviour?
Thank you so much

Comment: Please copy/post the error you got into your question

Answer (score 0):

Assuming table has a primary key = id you can try:

```
SET SQL_SAFE_UPDATES=0;
update table table1 
join  (select  id, sum(billsec)  s from table 
            group  by id having  sum(billsec) < 1000) t1  
on (t1.id = table1.id)
set table1.skipbill = 1
```

Comment: sadly i cannot assumed id as primary key.
when you group by id, how you can achieve the sum ?
thanks you anyway

Comment: What is the primary key of the table, or unique key

Comment: If there is no way to identify a row in a table what do you want to sum over in order to get the sum of billsec?  I think it would  be helpful if you clarify your question by showing the create table definitions.

Comment: the key of table is the whole fieldset.
the real table is composed also by others fields, one of these is calldate which represent the order i want to follow in the iteration process.
The full scenario is that i have a Call detail record table in which i have the calls originated by a pbx(calldate, billing seconds, customer, called number, etcetc). i also have another table where there are stored promotion like "for customer A, 1000 seconds of call are gratis from date B to date C"

Comment: So you want to sum the billing_seconds for each customer?  Then do you have  an id for that, like the customer_id?  It doesn't need to be a primary key for the table, but rather a foreign key (declared or not).  In other words use something like the above but use the customer_id in place of the id.

Comment: i 've modified the question with a more appropriate explanation and example. thank you

Comment: the question has moved here;
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27501451/sql-update-from-a-complex-select